# Angular testing: using fakeAsync with async/await

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-material

Angular Material provides [component harnesses](https://material.angular.io/guide/using-component-harnesses) for testing, which lets you interact with their components by `await`ing promises, like this:

```js
  it('should click button', async () => {
    const matButton = await loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness);
    await matButton.click();
    expect(...);
  });
```

But what if the button click triggers a delayed operation? Normally I would use `fakeAsync()`/`tick()` to handle it:

```js
  it('should click button', fakeAsync(() => {
    mockService.load.and.returnValue(of(mockResults).pipe(delay(1000)));
    // click button
    tick(1000);
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(...);
  }));
```

But is there any way I can do both in the same test?

Wrapping the `async` function inside `fakeAsync()` gives me "Error: The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function", presumably because once it finishes an `await`, it's no longer in the same function I passed to `fakeAsync()`.

Do I need to do something like this -- starting a fakeAsync function after the await? Or is there a more elegant way?

```js
  it('should click button', async () => {
    mockService.load.and.returnValue(of(mockResults).pipe(delay(1000)));
    const matButton = await loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness);

    fakeAsync(async () => {
      // not awaiting click here, so I can tick() first
      const click = matButton.click(); 
      tick(1000);
      fixture.detectChanges();
      await click;
      expect(...);
    })();
  });
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`fakeAsync(async () => {...})` is a valid construct.

Moreover, Angular Material team is [explicitly testing this scenario](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/b9f761a7283e7525cb569118e4fa0e937cf0d37f/src/cdk/testing/tests/testbed.spec.ts#L87).

```js
it('should wait for async operation to complete in fakeAsync test', fakeAsync(async () => {
        const asyncCounter = await harness.asyncCounter();
        expect(await asyncCounter.text()).toBe('5');
        await harness.increaseCounter(3);
        expect(await asyncCounter.text()).toBe('8');
      }));
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Looks like this was fixed a few months after I posted.

Comment: It is valid, but also risky. If your await is applied to a microtask, you don't have any issues because fakeAsync flushes microtasks at the end. If it is macrotask tough, you get an error. `tick` can't help you after the `await` anymore because it would already be executed in that macrotask.

Answer (score 6):

After updating from Angular 12 to 14, tests that were previously running without issue started to fail. The specific tests that were failing depended on both `fakeAsync` as well as `async`.

The resolution in my case was to add the following `target` to the `tsconfig.spec.json`

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "module": "CommonJs",
    "target": "ES2016", // Resolved fakeAsync + async tests errors
    "types": ["jest"]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.spec.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

A contrived test example:

```
it('should load button with exact text', fakeAsync(async () => {
  const buttons = await loader.getAllHarnesses(
    MatButtonHarness.with({ text: 'Testing Button' })
  );

  tick(1000);

  expect(buttons.length).toBe(1);
  expect(await buttons[0].getText()).toBe('Testing Button');
}));
```

I was getting the following error and it pointed directly to the `tick(1000)`:

> The code should be running in the fakeAsync zone to call this function

After adding the `ES2016` target to my `tsconfig.spec.json` all issues were resolved.

I use Jest, so those using other test runners may not have the same resolution.

Comment: thank you, this solved my issue. After upgrading to Jest 29.5.0 fakeAsync errors related to tick() appeared for tests that passed just fine under Jest 28.x.

Comment: I could absolutely kiss you right now. Does anybody know why this fixes it?

Comment: It works, but it's compiling your tests & "real" code to a different target. Thus you're testing different "compiled" code. This is not the best solution. You should upgrade you test code when you upgrade your "real" code (when you upgrade your compilation target).

Comment: I think this is related with a known issue in Angular where ZoneJS doesn't work for ES2017 and later: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31730

Answer (score 2):

I just released a test helper that lets you do exactly what you're looking for. Among other features, it allows you to use material harnesses in a `fakeAsync` test and control the passage of time as you describe.

The helper automatically runs what you pass to its `.run()` method in the fake async zone, and it can handle `async/await`. It would look like this, where you create the `ctx` helper in place of `TestBed.createComponent()` (wherever you have done that):

```js
it('should click button', () => {
  mockService.load.and.returnValue(of(mockResults).pipe(delay(1000)));
  ctx.run(async () => {
    const matButton = await ctx.getHarness(MatButtonHarness);
    await matButton.click();
    ctx.tick(1000);
    expect(...);
  });
});
```

The library is called `@s-libs/ng-dev`. Check out the documentation for this particular helper [here](https://simontonsoftware.github.io/s-libs/ng-dev/classes/componentcontextnext.html) and let me know about any issues via github [here](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/s-libs).

Answer (score 1):

You should not need a (real) `async` inside `fakeAsync`, at least to control the simulated flow of time.  The point of `fakeAsync` is to allow you to replace `await`s with `tick` / `flush`.  Now, when you actually need the value, I think you're stuck reverting to `then`, like this:

```js
  it('should click button', fakeAsync(() => {
    mockService.load.and.returnValue(of(mockResults).pipe(delay(1000)));
    const resultThing = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css("div.result"));
    loader.getHarness(MatButtonHarness).then(matButton => {
      matButton.click(); 
      expect(resultThing.textContent).toBeFalsy(); // `Service#load` observable has not emitted yet
      tick(1000); // cause observable to emit
      expect(resultThing.textContent).toBe(mockResults); // Expect element content to be updated
    });
  }));
```

Now, because your test body function is inside a call to `fakeAsync`, it should 1) not allow the test to complete until all Promises created (including the one returned by `getHarness`) are resolved, and 2) fail the test if there are any pending tasks.

(As an aside, I don't think you need a `fixture.detectChanges()` before that second `expect` if you're using the `async` pipe with the Observable returned by your Service, because the `async` pipe explicitly pokes the owner's change detector whenever its internal subscription fires.  I'd be interested to know if I'm wrong, though.)

Comment: Why would using a `then` be preferred over async/await? Seems silly

Comment: `fakeAsync` works by monkey-patching runtime behavior of the global Promise object, but there are no hooks in the browser for modifying the behavior of `async/await` statements.  It's the reason why [you can't emit native async functions without breaking Zone](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31730).  Using an `await` statement in your spec, that is eventually downleveled by your transpiler before running, might be fine though.